# Error when executing bcp command

Tags: sql, bcp

I have the following code that is executing `bcp` command:

```
declare @bcpCommand varchar(1024)
declare @sharedFolder varchar(500)
declare @environment varchar(5)
declare @customerCode varchar(5)
declare @parserConfig varchar(5)
declare @bucketAssign varchar(10)
declare @dateFormat varchar(8)
declare @dateSource varchar(128)
declare @tempbcp varchar(1024)
declare @userId varchar(128)
declare @password varchar(128)
declare @RC int

set @sharedFolder = '\\RemoteServer\TestFolder\DataFeed\'
set @environment = 'DEV'
set @customerCode = '123'
set @parserConfig = '100'
set @bucketAssign = 'CreditCard'
set @dateFormat = '20151507'
set @dateSource = 'TestServer'
set @userId = 'testId'
set @password = 'testPwd'

set @bcpCommand = 'bcp " testDB.dbo.TestTable" out "'
set @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + @sharedFolder + 'Transaction-' + 
                    @environment + '-' + 
                    @customerCode + '-' + 
                    @parserConfig + '-' +
                    @bucketAssign + '-' +
                    @dateFormat + '.txt " -U"' + @userId + '" -P"' + @password + '" -S"' + @dateSource + '" -c -t^| -r\n'

exec @RC = master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

When executing it I have the followoing error:

> An error occurred while processing the command line.

However when executing exactly the same statement with `select statement` from the same `table` and specidying `queryout` option imstead of `out` option, everything just works fine.

How can I fix that so, I can execute `bcp` from a `table`?

Comment: why do you set the `@bcpcommand` twice?

Comment: I append to @bcpCommand

Comment: sorry..i missed that